# Is it possible to integrate Facebook Conversations with non Facebook Identities?

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I have a set of users who will never use Facebook on my site.  Then again, I have users who insist on it.

I need to have a forum (like Facebook conversations) on my site so users can interact with it.  I know I could homebrew this, but would like the native FB integration.

Is it possible to use FB Conversations with non FB-integrated accounts (any other authentication system)?

Answer (score 0):

You can also allow third-party authenticated users via Yahoo, AOL and Hotmail.  Instructions are listed on [the Facebook Social Plugins documentation site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/):

> **How do I enable users to comment using other login providers?**
>
> On the settings section of the plugin, you can choose to enable third
>   party login on your comments boxes. Currently this will enable users
>   to comment using a Yahoo!, AOL or Hotmail account.